# Why node Failed commissioning while setting up MAAS?

Tags: maas

I installed MAAS and tried to add nodes but after few minutes of commissioning process its get fail.

I have ubuntu server 14.04 64bit with MAAS setup and having nodes in network with ubuntu 14.04 32 bit.

Server is having to Ethernet card. One is on DHCP and other with static IP.
All other nodes in network have static ip with Gateway and DNS as Server static IP.

Is there any issues with this configuration or any other problem for commissioning failure?

Answer (score 0):

The big issue that I'm having is similar, the default commissioning timeout is set to 10 minutes.  In theory, BEFORE running the "juju bootstrap" command you can alter this "bootstrap-timeout" to be something like 1800 (30 minutes) instead but this doesn't seem to be configurable after you've run the bootstrap command.

The documents suggest that you can just edit the environments.yaml file and it will adhere to your suggested update but I'm not seeing that actually happen.